# How to optimize MySQL UPDATE request?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update the 100K rows in a table. But the query is executed very very slowly.
Some mathematical functions is not in SQL, because used PHP, example `asinh`

```
<?php
 $n = pow(2, 6);
$sql = "";
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=****';
$user = '****';
$password = '****';
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
try {
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $dbh->beginTransaction();
    $stmt = $dbh->query('SELECT id, lat FROM data');

       while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
            {
                 $idRow = $row['id'];
                $latRow = $row['lat'];    
                 $y = floor(1 - asinh(tan(deg2rad($latRow))))/2*$n;
                 $sql .= " UPDATE data_update";
                 $sql .= " SET  ySet= '" . $y . "'";
                 $sql .= " WHERE ";
                 $sql .= "id = " . $idRow . "; ";
            }
   $dbh->exec($sql);    
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $dbh->rollBack();
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: Fire the first 10K and then next one and so on...

Comment: Break down what that formula does and implement it in sql.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an index on id.

```sql
ALTER TABLE `data_update` ADD PRIMARY KEY(`id`);
```

Answer (score 0):

For inserts you can group several inserts in only one statement, improving a lot the performance. In this case, the only solutions I find are:
1) grouping coincidence results if you know there are going to be repeated results, so you can save in an array the grouped ids by result ( $ids[$y][] = $newId ), and then implode and execute once per group ( update xxx where id in ( implode(',', $ids[$y] ) ). But as they're floats I'm not sure this will work at all, or if it will reduce the time for inserts.

2) Other possible improvement could be writting the sentences in a file  ( perform a file_put_contents each 500 statements or so, and don't forget to use FILE_APPEND ) and then execute the file load from mysql console as >source /my/file/path;

This latter solution is simpler and it's probably going to improve your performance, while the former not.